# WCF - Injecting into a Custom UserNamePasswordValidator with MEF

Tags: wcf, mef

I have a WCF Service which is using DI via MEF. That part is working fine.
I also have a Custom UserNamePasswordValidator which works as long as I use a parameterless constructor and 'new' everything up. However I would like to introduce MEF into that as well.

The service is hosted in IIS so I have to intercept it somewhat to get MEF to work as it is.
I've provided cross sections of my code below and any help would be appreciated!

Here is my web.config: -

```
        <behavior name="StandardServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
           customUserNamePasswordValidatorType=
               "WebService.Validators.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator, WebService" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="67108864" />
    </behavior>
```

My custom validator is as follows: -

```
    [Export(typeof(ICustomUserNamePasswordValidator))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class CustomUserNamePasswordValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator, ICustomUserNamePasswordValidator
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public CustomUserNamePasswordValidator([NotNull] IConnectionProvider connectionProvider)
    {
    }
    .....
}
```

I'm using a custom attribute on my Web Service called WebServiceExport, which subclasses the MEF Export attribute and includes an InstanceProvider: -

```
    [WebServiceExport(typeof(IGeneralService))]
public class GeneralService : IGeneralService
{
     ....
}
```

Here is the Export Attribute: -

```
    public class WebServiceExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IContractBehavior, IContractBehaviorAttribute
{
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription description, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatch)
    {
        var contractType = description.ContractType;
        dispatch.InstanceProvider = new MefInstanceProvider(contractType);
    }
    ....
}
```

And finally here is the Instance Provider: -

```
    public class MefInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    public MefInstanceProvider(Type serviceContract)
    {
        _serviceContract = serviceContract;
    }

    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
         BuildInstance(); //compose MEF parts
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: The thing about attributes is that as you probably know, they are only used if something is configured to look for them in the first place - MEF particularly so as it is at odds with WCF config files.  I think if you want to go the MEF route you would probably want to do away with WCF .config files entirely and control object creation entirely through MEF.  It's somewhat counter-productive to use dynamic plug-in-style DI (as MEF can provide) when the concrete type is mentioned in a static config file anyway. You may as well just use a _class factory_.

Comment: The WebServiceExport attribute already works without any config. Yeah I'd like to do away with the config option which specifies the custom validator but that means that MEF needs to take over that part...and I don't know how to achieve that.